# mongodb tuple comparison (ordered)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, tuples, comparison

Just similar to this question: [mongodb query multiple pairs using $in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984354/mongodb-query-multiple-pairs-using-in)

I want to find first 10 full names with `(first, last) >= ('John', 'Smith')`. It is simple with MySQL:

```
SELECT first, last 
FROM names
WHERE (first, last) >= ('John', 'Smith') 
ORDER BY first, last 
LIMIT 10
```

In MongoDB maybe something like:

```
db.Names.find({ "[first, last]": { $gte: [ "John", "Smith"] }})
   .sort({first: 1, last: 1})
   .limit(10)
```

But I do not know how to write the correct and simple query.

This may be work but too verbose:

```
db.Names.find({ $or: [
           { first: "John", last: { $gte: "Smith" }},
           { first: { $gt: "John" }}
    ]}).sort(...)
```

Comment: Please give feedback on your this and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984354/mongodb-query-multiple-pairs-using-in/58206489#58206489) question . Let me know I can find better solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use below **mongoDB** query in respect of this **mysql** query

```
SELECT first, last 
FROM names
WHERE (first, last) >= ('John', 'Smith') 
ORDER BY first, last 
LIMIT 10
```

Mongodb query

```
db.Names.find(
  { $expr: {
      $or: [
       { $gte: [{ $strLenCP: "$first" }, { $strLenCP: "John" }] },
       { $gte: [{ $strLenCP: "$last" }, { $strLenCP: "Smith" }] }
      ]
  }}, 
  // project from mongodb result same as select in mysql 
  { first: 1, _id: 0, last: 1 })
  // sort in mongodb
 .sort({ first: 1, last: 1 })
  // with limit 10
 .limit(10);
```